# How to enable PWA feature on existing blazor project

Tags: c#, blazor

When create a new project of blazor wasm, we can choose to enable PWA. What if we want to enable it in already created blazor wasm project.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new blazor wasm app with pwa enabled :

```sh
dotnet new blazorwasm -o MyNewProject --pwa`
```

And copy:

- *wwwroot/icon-512.png*
- *wwwroot/manifest.json*
- *wwwroot/service-worker.js*
- *wwwroot/service-worker.published.js*

Then update {BlazorApp}.csproj to add reference to the service worker:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
...
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And update *index.html* to add link, icon and script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
...
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
</head>

<body>
...
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And update *wwwroot/manifest.json* to feat your needs

```
{
  "name": "{Your app name}",
  "short_name": "{Your app short name}",
  "start_url": "./",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#03173d",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```